# Trouble on binding links with HTML5 'data-*' attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I have the following code:

```
# view.html.erb

link_to("Title 1", url1, :remote => true, :method => :patch, :data => {:type => :html, :custom => true}
# <a rel="nofollow" href="/url1" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Title 1</a>

link_to("Title 2", url2, :remote => true, :method => :patch, :data => {:type => :html, :custom => true}
# <a rel="nofollow" href="/url2" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Title 2</a>

link_to("Title 3", url3, :remote => true, :method => :patch, :data => {:type => :html, :custom => true}
# <a rel="nofollow" href="/url3" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Title 3</a>


# application.js

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-remote][data-custom]').bind({
    click: function(event) {
      $(document).on('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
        $(this).replaceWith(data);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

For instance, when the link `Title 1` is clicked then, on success, the response/returned data is the following link (the same behavior applies when click links `Title 2` and `Title 3`):

```
link_to("Replaced 1", url1, :remote => true, :method => :patch, :data => {:type => :html, :custom => true}
# <a rel="nofollow" href="/url1" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Replaced 1</a>
```

As you can see the response/returned link is almost the same as the original link (that is, it has `data-*` attributes as-like the original clicked link) and so the JavaScript binding should happen even for that link after it replaces the DOM.

However, if I continue to click other links as-like the `Title 2` then both the `Title 1` and the `Title 2` links are replaced on the front-end content resulting in the following whole HTML code:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/url2" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Replaced 2</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/url2" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Replaced 2</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/url3" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Title 3</a>
```

For completeness, when I click `Title 3` then the resulting in the following whole HTML code:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/url3" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Replaced 3</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/url3" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Replaced 3</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/url3" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Replaced 3</a>
```

It seems that the JavaScript binding isn't working as expected (note repeated `Replaced <N>` links). I do not understand why it could happen but the expected behavior is to just replace one link each time that link is clicked.

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you add code showing how your AJAX functionality works?

Comment: @awexfwex - Yes, I can add code but I don't know what code. The `ruby-on-rails` question tag (that you removed after editing the question itself) was there because `link_to(..., :remote => true, :method => :patch, ...` is [a Rails AJAX functionality](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js).

Comment: Somewhere, you must have some Javascript code performing the actual ajax call. Post that. 
The ruby code is just generating the html to be used, and doesn't seem necessary for the question.

Comment: The code that performs the AJAX call is somewhere in the [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) file.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was totally wrong. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bind function attaches the event handler to the actual element at the time of calling. So when you recreate the link, it doesn't have an event handler attached for click. Instead, you should use either .on(..) or .delegate(..), and attach the event handler itself to a wrapper element above the links.

Conversely, you are creating a new ajax success handler every time a link is clicked, so they build up. I'm not sure how your AJAX functionality is implemented, but you should either have the ajax:success event attached only to the function/object consuming it, or have it attached to the document only once, where you would need to pass in the element that was clicked to start the request.

Untested example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#link-list").on('ajax:success', "a[data-remote][data-custom]", function(xhr, data, status) {
            $(this).replaceWith(data);
        });
    });
</script>
 <div id="link-list"> <!-- // wrapping element to attach event handlers to -->
    <a rel="nofollow" href="/url1" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Title 1</a>
    <a rel="nofollow" href="/url2" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Title 2</a>
    <a rel="nofollow" href="/url3" data-type="html" data-custom="true" data-remote="true" data-method="patch">Title 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it generates the exact same behavior as described in the question. I think the issue is related to the binding since it binds for replacing all links, not just one. Probably you are rigth when you say "you should have event attached only to the object consuming it".